# How to use axios to upload image files through http

Tags: javascript, axios

I am using axios to upload image file to server but failed. Below is the code:

```
let data = new FormData()
data.append('image', image)
axios({
type: type,
payload: {
  request: {
    url: url,
    method: 'post',
    timeout: 60000,
    headers: {
      'ACCESS_TOKEN': token,
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
    data: data
  }
})
```

I got 400 Bad Request error. Below is the response from server:

```
{"timestamp":1480851939951,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException","message":"Required request part 'image' is not present.","path":"/upload/image"}
```

I have used postman to test the server api and it works fine. What wrong with my code?

**EDIT1**
The image object was got from . Below is the code to get the image object

```
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function () {
      let image = fr.result()  //image is got here

    }
    fr.readAsDataURL(file);
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? What do you mean by append?

Comment: where is the file object from?

Comment: The file is just a url string

Comment: did you find a solution to this?